# Show only date in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a JSON array like this one:

```
[
{
    "user": "345",
    "createdOn": "2015-09-01 13:17:22"
},
{
    "user": "432",
    "createdOn": "2015-09-01 13:27:56"
}
```

]

In a `<div>` tag I am doing this:

```
 <div> class="row" ng-repeat="item in array"             
         {{item.createdOn}}
 </div>
```

The output is : 2015-09-01 13:50:59, but I don't want the time part to be shown, i.e. required output is just 2015-09-01.
I tried using `filter` but unsuccessfully. Give me some knowledge on this, please.

Comment: use split if it's always a string, or use Date instead and then filter it

Comment: `{{ item.createdOn.slice(0,10) }}`

Comment: Did it solved your issue? Or do you need more details or answers?

Comment: @Amina solved...thanks

Comment: So you can click accept answers, of the solution you most like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.dateOnly= function(timestamp) {
    return new Date(timestamp);
}
```

will help

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: Ok.. will do it now ..Thanks for warning me:)

Answer (score 8):

If your object is fetching data from db and timestamp is returned properly, and your date is formatted as 'yyyy-MM-dd', this should work.

```
{{item.createdOn| date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

Otherwise, format your string as a Date. (This is detailed in other answers.)

Comment: What is the error in your console ? It should work, try clearing cache

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: If your object is fetching data from db and timestamp is retuned /date id properly return it should work....else format your string in Date as suggested in above answers

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Angular filter But Date filters only work with Date objects so first thing you need to convert your strings into Date object.

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in array">
    {{getDateFormat(item.createdOn)|date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
  </div>
```

Controller:

```
  $scope.array = [{
    "user": "345",
    "createdOn": "2015-09-01 13:17:22"
  }, {
    "user": "432",
    "createdOn": "2015-09-01 13:27:56"
  }];

  $scope.getDateFormat = function(timestamp) {
    return new Date(timestamp);
  }
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QG6QS52EuIwQ2LMJrYfe?p=preview)

Comment: i tried that..still it is showing both date and time

Answer (score 1):

The short answer:

### **Date filter in Angular works better with *Date* objects.**

*Please run this code snippet:*

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('a',function($scope){
$scope.a='2012-08-30 13:30:00'
$scope.b=new Date('2012-08-30 13:30:00')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app=app ng-controller=a>
{{a|date:'mm-dd-yy'}}
 <hr>
  {{b|date:'mm-dd-yy'}}
 </div>
```

**This is the fix for you code:**

```
var obj=    [{
    "user": "345",
    "createdOn": new Date("2015-09-01 13:17:22")
},
{
    "user": "432",
    "createdOn": new Date("2015-09-01 13:27:56")
}
]
```

You can see the example that when I use date object it works.

If you got the object from external sources you can convert it to Date objects. using this code:

```
for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++) obj[i].createdOn=new Date(obj[i].createdOn)
```

Comment: What if user is not allowed to touch JSON?

Comment: Please see the end of the answer, how to convert it to Date objects in the JSON. One line of for()

Comment: For var in loop is bad idea.. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Comment: Thank you. Changed to regular for()

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom filter in this case,

Try this,

***HTML :***

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="data in datas">
        {{data.createdOn | dateOnly}}
    </div>
</div>
```

***angularjs :***

```
angular.module("myapp", []).controller('MainCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope){
    var data = [
    {
        "user": "345",
        "createdOn": "2015-09-01 13:17:22"
    },
    {
        "user": "432",
        "createdOn": "2015-09-01 13:27:56"
    }];

    $scope.datas = data;
    }])
    .filter("dateOnly", function(){
        return function(input){
            return input.split(' ')[0]; // you can filter your datetime object here as required.
        };
    });
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/z3ca8j9d/)